# When using np.where on a pandas datetime column, an "object" dtype value is returned. Is this expected behavior?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

I am not being smug with this question, I genuinely wonder if this is how it's supposed to work.

I am working on a pandas dataframe using method chaining and assigning new columns based on conditions. One of te column assignments uses np.where() to check whether or not another column contains a value or a NaN/NaT for the same row. If it contains a value, I want to assign that value to the new column. If it's a NaN/NaT, I want to pd.to_datetime('1900-01-01 00:00:00') instead.

Here's some sample code to recreate my problem (in the real code, the assignments come after a bunch of operations on the df, which is why I'm using lambda):

```
example_df = pd.DataFrame({'animal': ['Falcon', 'Falcon',
                              'Parrot', 'Parrot'],
                            'time': [pd.to_datetime('2023-01-01 23:59:58'), pd.to_datetime('2023-01-01 23:59:58'), pd.to_datetime('2023-01-01 23:59:58'), pd.to_datetime('2023-01-01 23:59:58')]})

example_df.assign(same_time = lambda df_:np.where(df_["time"].isna(), pd.to_datetime('1900-01-01 00:00:00'), df_["time"]))
# Or this, same result:
example_df["same_time"] = np.where(example_df["time"].isna(), pd.to_datetime('1900-01-01 00:00:00'), example_df["time"])
```

The "time" column has dtype datetime64[ns], but the new column is has dtype "object".

[image: Result image:]

It does not help to wrap the return value in pd.to_datetime (i.e. **pd.to_datetime(df_["time"])**), I'm still getting the object dtype returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numpy datetime data type seems incompatible with the pandas one, so it will convert the data to an object. I recommend using the pandas [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) method instead.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

example_df = pd.DataFrame({'animal': ['Falcon', 'Falcon', 'Parrot', 'Parrot'],
                           'time': [pd.to_datetime('2023-01-01 23:59:58'),
                                    pd.to_datetime('2023-01-01 23:59:58'),
                                    pd.to_datetime('2023-01-01 23:59:58'),
                                    np.nan]})
example_df = example_df.assign(same_time=example_df["time"].where(~example_df["time"].isna(), 
                                                                  pd.to_datetime('1900-01-01 00:00:00')))
```

With that, `example_df` becomes:

```py
   animal                time           same_time
0  Falcon 2023-01-01 23:59:58 2023-01-01 23:59:58
1  Falcon 2023-01-01 23:59:58 2023-01-01 23:59:58
2  Parrot 2023-01-01 23:59:58 2023-01-01 23:59:58
3  Parrot                 NaT 1900-01-01 00:00:00
```

---

Update:

Instead of using `where` and inverting the `isna` result, you can use the [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) method, which is pretty much the opposite of `where`, i.e. it replaces when it evaluates to `True`.

```py
example_df = example_df.assign(same_time=example_df["time"].mask(example_df["time"].isna(),
                                                                 pd.to_datetime('1900-01-01 00:00:00')))
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. The pandas where does indeed work.